# I want to upload image using ajax

Tags: jquery

I want to upload image using ajax I got the following code from the internet: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

```
<script>
$(function(){
      $("#imgfile").on("click", function(){
      alert("hello");
        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'imageupload.php',  
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {  
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myXhr.upload){ 
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); 
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function(data){
               alert(data);

            },
            error: function(){
              alert("error check it");
            },
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
      });
   </script>
```

and the html

```
<input id="imgfile" type="file" name="imgfile">
```

I want the script to be executed when the user selects the image and ready to be processed. I don't want separate upload button. I tried and failed.

Answer (score 1):

> *I want the script to be executed when the user selects the image and ready to be processed. and I dont want separate upload button I tried and failed.*

For this you have use `change` event instead:

```
$("#imgfile").on("change", function(){
     // all code
});
```

`change` event gets fired when you select a file in the input file element.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution using jQuery and the AJAX Upload plugin seem to work for me.
Try this
http://zurb.com/playground/ajax-upload